# sed + update /etc/grub.conf in spite this link file

Tags: sed, rhel, grub, links

I read that sed command sometime cant edit files that are links as

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  Aug 31  2008 /etc/grub.conf -> ../boot/grub/grub.conf
```

so is it wrong to use sed as

```
sed -i 's/find/replace/g' /etc/grub.conf
```

or the right way is to works only on the non link file as ?

```
sed -i 's/find/replace/g' /boot/grub/grub.conf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason to be careful with sed and symlinks, is that when sed modifies a file inplace, it will destroy the link and make a new file.  For example:

```
bash-[622]$ echo abc > a
bash-[623]$ ln -s a b
bash-[624]$ ls -la
total 32
drwxr-xr-x   2 tim      staff        233 Mar  2 10:31 ./
drwxrwxrwt   4 root     sys          612 Mar  2 10:29 ../
-rw-r--r--   1 tim      staff          4 Mar  2 10:31 a
lrwxrwxrwx   1 tim      staff          1 Mar  2 10:31 b -> a
bash-[625]$ cat a
abc
bash-[626]$ cat b
abc
bash-[627]$ sed -i 's/abc/def/g' b
bash-[628]$ ls -la
total 32
drwxr-xr-x   2 tim      staff        233 Mar  2 10:31 ./
drwxrwxrwt   4 root     sys          612 Mar  2 10:29 ../
-rw-r--r--   1 tim      staff          4 Mar  2 10:31 a
-rw-r--r--   1 tim      staff          4 Mar  2 10:31 b
bash-[629]$ cat a
abc
bash-[630]$ cat b
def
```

In order to work with symlinks in a safer manner, if your version of sed is GNU Sed, you can use the `--follow-symlinks` option of sed.

```
bash-[632]$ echo abc > a
bash-[633]$ ln -s a b
bash-[634]$ ls -la
total 32
drwxr-xr-x   2 tim      staff        233 Mar  2 10:33 ./
drwxrwxrwt   4 root     sys          612 Mar  2 10:32 ../
-rw-r--r--   1 tim      staff          4 Mar  2 10:33 a
lrwxrwxrwx   1 tim      staff          1 Mar  2 10:33 b -> a
bash-[635]$ cat a
abc
bash-[636]$ cat b
abc
bash-[637]$ sed --follow-symlinks -i 's/abc/def/g' b
bash-[638]$ ls -la
total 32
drwxr-xr-x   2 tim      staff        233 Mar  2 10:33 ./
drwxrwxrwt   4 root     sys          612 Mar  2 10:32 ../
-rw-r--r--   1 tim      staff          4 Mar  2 10:33 a
lrwxrwxrwx   1 tim      staff          1 Mar  2 10:33 b -> a
bash-[639]$ cat a
def
bash-[640]$ cat b
def
```

As you can see, when `--follow-symlinks is used`, the symlink is maintained, and the sed operation actually applies to file `a`.

So, in your example, if you broke the symlink between `/etc/grub.conf` -> `/boot/grub/grub.conf`, you would expect your changes to take place, only to find out that they weren't actually being applied to `/boot/grub/grub.conf`, and you could spend significant time troubleshooting why your boot is not working as expected.

Comment: so if we not have the flag --follow-symlinks then can we update the /boot/grub/grub.conf with sed

Comment: if you **do** have the `--follow-symlinks` option, then you can.

Comment: no I mean as sed s'/find/replace/g' /boot/grub/grub.conf   , while the option  --follow-symlinks not in sed

Comment: Yes.   You can safely use sed on the actual file without detaching the symlink from the file.